# Oxford comma when two last items in a list are "merged" into a single one by omitting the repeated word

Tags: punctuation, commas

> 1. Colons, dashes, question marks, and exclamation marks are ...
> 2. Colons, dashes, question marks and exclamation marks are ...
> 3. Colons, dashes, question and exclamation marks are ...
> 4. Colons, dashes, question, and exclamation marks are ...

The Oxford comma is usually optional, but personally I prefer to use it whenever possible. However, I'm not sure it will be correct to use it in the 4th example. Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that "Colons, dashes, question and exclamation marks  ..." is a list with only three items, but the last is a complex item, therfore it should be witten as:

> Colons, dashes, and question and exclamation marks ...

by a user of the "oxford" or serial comma. Your version 4:

> <s>Colons, dashes, question, and exclamation marks</s>

I think is thus incorrect.